# yt won't work after the ubuntu upgrade

Tags: firefox, 15.10, youtube, html5, h264

So I upgraded to the beautiful Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf and the only probem I found is that YT videos doesn't work anymore and it changes the new video interface with the old one to work somehow.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

So I get the error "An error occurred. Please try again later." to the new interface as you can see in the photos.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

What solved this for me is setting `media.mediasource.webm.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`

I also have the following keys set to `true` manually:

- `media.mediasource.enabled`
- `media.fragmented-mp4.exposed`
- `media.fragmented-mp4.ffmpeg.enabled`

These settings let you adjust the video quality as well (to me it does not work out of the box, everything is only available on 360p). Here is the full config I have, for reference:

Settings for *media.fragmented**:
[image: Settings for media.fragmented*]

Settings for *media.mediasource**:
[image: Settings for media.mediasource*]

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me. I would suggest to [set YouTube to always use HTML5](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5/). <s>If you still have issues, then please add the info you get when you click "Learn More" to your question.</s> (Turns out there is no further useful information.)

---

## Investigation and troubleshooting

I think I was able to reproduce this issue and up until now I didn't modify any settings in about:config as Zoltan mentions while HTML5 versions of YouTube and Vimeo have both been working fine for me. I just installed `gstreamer1.0-libav` which got me this far on [YouTube's HTML5](https://www.youtube.com/html5) page:

[image]

Regarding your error message, as I said I never modified related settings in Firefox or installed any extensions or plug-ins that might change these on your behalf. You should check entries beginning with `media.` in your about:config and reset them back to default via double click or context menu → reset. You can or should leave the `media.gmp-` settings alone, then restart Firefox and HTML5 YouTube should be working as intended. The is as close to the default as possible with libav/ffmpeg providing the necessary codecs.

The issue seems to be triggered by an **inconsistent configuration**, which confuses YouTube, especially you when don't restart Firefox and Flash is also still in the mix (you should restrict usage of Flash and only enable it when necessary). Another trigger could be that H.264 and VPx content gets mixed one video would play, but the other has issues and cause the message you got. I imagine an ad loading before the actual video, the ad would not play, playback would not continue and throw the error message, while the actual video would have played just fine. N.B. I'm a NoScript user and notice that I don't see as much ad clips as I see without.

## Reproducibly enable all HTML5 video features

[image]

With everything set to a default (reproducible) state you can try to enable all features on the HTML5 page. Here is how:

Install `gstreamer1.0-libav` or the latest available version of the package if you haven't already. Then set the following settings to true in about:config (the current default in Firefox 41 is false):

```
media.mediasource.enabled;true
media.mediasource.webm.enabled;true
media.fragmented-mp4.exposed;true
media.fragmented-mp4.ffmpeg.enabled;true
```

The following are just to check, they should be enabled by default:

```
media.gstreamer.enabled;true
media.webm.enabled;true
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well. The youtube html5 gives me a blue checkmark on all options. If you play a video, then it works. However, if you disable webm, then it fails like in the top post.

Looking into it further, you find that it fails to play every video of type "video/mp4", which basically means that the h264 decoder is recognised (as shown by youtube) but not working.

The obvious solution is to enable webm/vp9. Which works for youtube (partially), but not everything else.

So far, I haven't found a solution for everything.

Answer (score 0):

about:config

switch media.fragmented-mp4.use-blank-decoder  to true.

Other settings:
media.mediasource.mp4.enabled to true
media.fragmented-mp4.* to true

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. Installing [RestrictedFormats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) somehow helped:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After that `An error occurred. Please try again later` message still appears but at leas the video loads a second later or after a reload.